# Codeigniter not save data in excel

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can't set cell value in excel that error are

> ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: No such file or
>   directory.How to solution edit problem ZipArchive::close():
>
> Message:  ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: No
>   such file or directory
>
> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught PHPExcel_Writer_Exception: Could not
>   close zip file php://output. in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/paym/backoffice/api/v1/application/third_party/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php:389
>   My code:

```
     $fileName = 'data-'.time().'.csv';
     $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
     $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'room');
     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B1', 'electric');
     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', 'water');
     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D1', 'total_price');
     $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel,'Excel2007');

     header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 
     header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$fileName); 
     header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); 
     $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. In order to help you, please provide some more information and tell us what excactly your question is.

Comment: It might be worth looking at PHPSpreadsheet as PHPExcel is now no longer supported.